# Groovy, how to ignore version?

Tags: groovy, bamboo

I'm new to groovy and scripting and need some help. How do I ignore version? For ex: I need version 1, 3, 4, 5 and ignore 2.  I have this now:

```
def ignores = []
ignoreList.split(',')
if (version.contains
```

I'm using this script to run from CI Bamboo build. I just need the script that to skip the certain version and specify that version in the format

> '2','5','7'

in Bamboo build plan

Answer (score 1):

Here is an arithmetic operation in Groovy you will like. ;)

```
assert [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] - 2 == [1, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can simply remove the ignored version from a list of versions by using [`minus()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#minus%28java.lang.Object%29) on List. Another variant of minus() is also to remove a  collection from a collection as:

```
assert [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] - [2, 5] == [1, 3, 4]
```

You can also use `.minus()` explicitly as a method without using the overridden `-` operator and end up with the same operation:

```
assert [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].minus([2, 5]) == [1, 3, 4]
```

Come on, say it..... !! Yes, you do like Groovy, don't you?.. :)

Comment: I'm using this script to run from CI Bamboo build, I just need script that will skip the certain version and specify that version in this format '2','5','7' in Bamboo build plan.

Comment: `[2, 5, 7].join(/,/)` is what you are looking for? @user3380618

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can check if a version is in your list of versions to ignore.

```
def versionsToIgnore = [2]
if (!versionsToIgnore.contains(version)) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

Comment: I guess my question was not complete, what if I have more then one version to ignore for ex: 2,7,9 that's why I try to use ignoreList.split (',')? then pass ignore versions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you declare a variable as

```
def ignores = []
```

you are declaring a list. A quick way to check is to get its class

```
log.info ignores.class //log.info is used in soapUI which i am using to write this code

//returns
class java.util.ArrayList
```

What you want to do is search for data in the list, this can be done by multiple methods one of the methods has been demonstrated by @grantmc you can also do a findAll or collect.

```
def words = ['ant', 'buffalo', 'cat', 'dinosaur']
assert words.findAll{ w -> w.size() > 4 } == ['buffalo', 'dinosaur']

def words = ['ant', 'buffalo', 'cat', 'dinosaur']
assert words.collect{ it[0] } == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

These examples can be found at http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections under `Enhanced Collection Methods`. That section also states

> In addition to findAll and collect shown above, you have methods like findIndexOf, grep, any, every, min, max, flatten, intersect, disjoint, sort, join and others. Simply look up the [GDK doco](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/) for more details. You might want to look up the added methods for Collection, List and Object to start with.
>
> Some more details about these methods can also be found in the Quick Start Guide under [JN1015-Collections](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections).

[Another good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136616/groovy-filter-criteria-on-findall-on-a-list) of a FindAll can be found on SO by @TimYates

Comment: I'm using this script to run from CI Bamboo build,  I just need script that will skip the certain version and specify that version in this format '2','5','7' in Bamboo build plan. Thanks for you answer,